# Testing async method with Moq and xUnit seemingly not thread safe?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, moq

I'm working on testing an asynchronous method with Moq and xUnit. The test runs fine the majority of the time, however it occasionally fails. Initially, I thought this was due to a flaw in my code in the method, until I realized that if it were running synchronously, this would not cause an issue. In addition, the test would fail more when there was an alternative setup on a Moq class in, say, another test.

This is a problem because it means I cannot reliably test my class, as it uses an asynchronous read from a stream as part of the class' core.

Below is the test.

```
    [Fact]
    public void FullMessageAsynchronouslyRead_RaiseMessageReceivedEvent()
    {
        var stream = new Mock<IRemoteStream>();
        var schema = new Mock<IMessageSerializationSchema>();
        var remote = new TCPRemote(stream.Object, schema.Object) as IRemote;
        var mockListener = new Mock<ITCPRemoteTestEventListener>();
        var message = Mock.Of<IMessage>();
        // Use manual reset event to ensure that we don't finish the test
        // until the async method has returned
        var reset = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        schema.Setup(x => x.Read(It.IsAny<byte[]>())).Returns(message);
        remote.MessageReceived += mockListener.Object.MessageReceived;
        stream.Setup(x => x.ReadAsync(It.IsAny<byte[]>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(1)
            .Callback(() => reset.Set());

        remote.ReadAsync();

        reset.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
        mockListener.Verify(x => x.MessageReceived(remote, message), Times.Once());
    }
```

This test should test that when I receive a *full message* (which is determined by checking whether `IMessageSerializationSchema.Read(byte[])` throws an exception or not) that the `MessageReceived` event is raised on `TCPRemote`. To test that it's raised, I make a test interface called `ITCPRemoteTestEventListener` and make a Mock of this interface, assign it as an event handler to `TCPRemote.MessageReceived` and then use Moq to verify it received a call to it's event callback exactly one time. I use a `ManualResetEvent` to try and keep the test somewhat synchronous, otherwise the test would likely always fail on slower systems (as the read operation is asynchronous).

Here is the code involved in the SUT's `ReadAsync` method.

```
    public void ReadAsync()
    {
        Array.Clear(_receiveBuffer, 0, 0);
        _ReadAsync(_receiveBuffer, 0, 0);
    }

    #region Internals
    private void _ReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, offset, count);
        _stream.ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count).ContinueWith(_ReadAsyncContinuation, segment);
    }

    private void _ReadAsyncContinuation(Task<int> readAsyncTask, object segment)
    {
        var seg = (ArraySegment<byte>)segment;
        var bytes = new byte[seg.Count];
        Array.Copy(_receiveBuffer, seg.Offset, bytes, 0, seg.Count);

        try
        {
            var message = _schema.Read(bytes);

            if (MessageReceived != null)
                MessageReceived(this, message);
        }
        catch (SerializedMessageNotFullyReceivedException)
        {
            _ReadAsync(_receiveBuffer, seg.Offset, ReceiveBufferSize - seg.Offset);
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Long story short, this was originally written such that it could automatically loop (calling `ReadAsync` would invoke `_ReadAsync` and then when `_ReadAsync` finished reading a message, it would invoke `ReadAsync` again, clearing the buffer and starting over) however I decided that was breaking the SRP of the class - or the function, at least - and removed that. That said, these set of methods

- Clear the receiving buffer (8024 bytes)
- Create an `ArraySegment` based on an offset and count on the receiving buffer
- Create the `Task<int>` for the reading task by invoking `IRemoteStream.ReadAsync(byte[],int,int)` and add a continuation to this task for `_ReadAsyncContinuation` with the `ArraySegment` created earlier passed as a parameter.
- check to see if the message is valid by asking the Schema - if it is, the Schema will simply return the message.
- Publish an event to `MessageReceived`.

As I mentioned though, this test is *very occasionally* failing (the `Verify` condition is not being satisfied). I know it has something to do with my threading, but I have no idea where to start. Ideas?

For brownie points: I know I need to put exclusive write locks to the receive buffer here; where should I be putting them?

Comment: By the way, I should note that I don't want to actually test asynchronously, I just want to test the functionality of these methods, however they just happen to be designed to be asynchronous.

Comment: What's the failure?  Is it the `Verify` statement stating the call never happened, or is it something else?

Comment: Sorry, yes, `Verify` occasionally states that `MessageReceived` was not invoked on the test listener